# Not able to download a file using spring webclient but the same works with BufferedInputStream

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

```
final WebClient client = WebClient.create();

Mono<byte[]> block = client.get()
                           .uri("urlxxx")
                           .header("Authorization", "xxx")
                           .retrieve()
                           .bodyToMono(byte[].class)).block()
    
Files.write(Paths.get("abc.tar.gz"), 
            Objects.requireNonNull(block.share().block()), 
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

but at this line `block.share()` it is giving me `nullpointerexception`.
I tried the same example with BufferedInputStream and can download the file. What am I missing here in the webclient code?

Answer (score 0):

The better way to follow the 'non-blocking' way instead of using InputStreams. You can convert body to `Flux<DataBuffer>` and write data buffers to a file using `DataBufferUtils`

```java
Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = webClient.get()
        .uri("http://resource.com")
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "token")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

DataBufferUtils.write(dataBufferFlux, 
                Path.of("/path_to_save_file/file.txt"), 
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE
        )
        .subscribe();
```